# Xpath for Scrapy script

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I'm trying to figure out which is the right Xpath without success due, this is the XML I am trying to extract from:

> 

```
    <div class="product-item__info">
        <a href="https://www.wong.pe/cafe-tostado-y-molido-house-blend-starbucks-bolsa-250-g-782449002/p" class="product-item__name" title="Café Tostado y Molido House Blend Starbucks® Bolsa 250 g">Café Tostado y Molido House Blend Starbucks® Bolsa 250 g</a>
        <div class="product-item__brand">Starbucks</div>
        <div class="product-item__description" style="display: none"></div>
        <label class="product-item__compare product-compare">
            <input type="checkbox" name="prod-compare-checkbox" class="product-compare__input">
```

I need the link and the brand. So far I tried, without success:

```
//div[@class="product-item__brand"]/text()   #for Brand
//a[starts-with(@href, "https://www.wong.pe/")]   #for link
```

What could it be? thanks

Comment: HTML is not XML. you can't parse incomplete/invalid HTML as XML.

Comment: Both XPath expression seem to be ok (for XML). They get both text nodes.

Comment: Yes, from the information provided, these are correct xpaths. You'll have to post more complete input, scrapy code, and output for a diagnosis of the real problem.